# H2 database won't open browser page on KUbuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, h2, chromium

I've been accessing the H2 database without problems, until I upgraded for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (which was a disaster for me - Ubuntu, not the upgrade) to KUbuntu 18.04 (which is working much better).  Now, H2 won't open a browser window for reasons I don't understand.

I run:

```
 java -jar h2-1.3.174.jar -url "jdbc:h2:~/hcs/application/demo/dcdemo;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE" -user SA
```

This used to open a window in my browser.  Now it just sits there.  Using `lsof -p <h2_pid>` I can see the port it is listening on and direct my web browser there manually.  Usually something like `localhost:34029`.  Then it works correctly.

More interesting, if I just run:

java -jar h2-1.3.174.jar

I get an error message:

```
Failed to start a browser to open the URL http://127.0.1.1:44177: Browser detection failed and system property h2.browser not set
```

I tried setting "h2.browser" as an environment variable, but it is not valid.

Digging around in the documentation and searching Google, I've not found where I can correctly point H2 towards my browser - Chromium Version 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 18.04 (64-bit) loaded in /usr/bin/chromium-browser.

How do I get H2 pointed in the right direction so I don't have to dig out lsof every few months?

Comment: It is worth noting, that I opened a ticket with H2 regarding this problem:  https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1774

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is silent on how this works and it bugged me enough that I went and read the H2 source code.  There are a few ways to set the browser:

1. As the java property h2.browser.
   For example: `java -Dh2.browser=/usr/bin/chromium-browser -jar h2-1.3.174.jar`
2. As the environment variable BROWSER.
   For example: `export BROWSER=/usr/bin/chromium-browser`

By default on Windows it will try whatever is set to handle URLs (rundll32).  On MACs it will try Safari.  On everything else (typically Linux), it will try running the following commands:

```
"chromium", "google-chrome", "firefox", "mozilla-firefox",
"mozilla", "konqueror", "netscape", "opera", "midori"
```

If all of those fail, then it will print the error message:

```
Browser detection failed and system property h2.browser not set
```

Since my (KUbuntu) Linux installation uses `chromium-browser`, it failed.

Comment: It should be noted that is has been fixed in newer versions of H2.  H2 1.4.198 does not have this problem as it is smarter about finding the web browser.

Comment: v. 1.4.199 still couldn't detect my browser, and I had to set the BROWSER environment variable for the application to start without error.

Comment: @jrahhali If it is still a problem, you should mention it to the H2 folks.  I opened this ticket: https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/1774 and they were responsive in trying to improve the error messages.  A ticket showing the problem is a new version of H2 might spur a fix.

Comment: This solution worked for 1.4.200 on CentOS 6 platform